# Ubuntu broken by installing and uninstalling the Gimp

Tags: package-management, restore

I installed the Gimp through the Software Center and it had to undo something. I lost LibreOffice, for example.

Then when I was done with the Gimp, I uninstalled it and tried to get my other stuff back. Now my desktop has no control bar on the left. Nor can I see the top bar. I can access the terminal though.

How can I undo all of what the Gimp removed and restore the previous settings?

Comment: You could *try* to reinstall the desktop  `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`, but I suspect that you have much deeper problems:  Gimp and LibreOffice do not interfere with each other, and should be able to run quite well together on your system

Comment: Yes I've had them together in the past. But that's what happened...

Comment: I just tried that it says stuff and then "unable to correct problems you have held broken packages

Comment: You might have to start with [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: Thanks I did sudo aptget update. It worked will restart and see. Didn't work yarg

Answer (score 0):

Well I would advice a new system installation. If you have your /home directory your good for this part of the installation. All of your files should be safe during the new installation. I believe.

Comment: Maybe I could do upgrade to new version? I am on an older one

Comment: I tend to agree with you, although it would be nice to know what happened to his system.  Often the 'let's re-install' answer is down-voted in Askubuntu

Comment: Ok. During the boot screen setup, check the system for error from the boot setup and repair it. M. Then get the  software versions of gimp and libreoffice. Then report the issue and ask them why they don't work together. :)

Comment: I have recovery mode is that the same? I have a dual boot. So I can check all file systems , update grub boot loader@ repair broken packages, drop to root shell prompt

Comment: Can you reinstall the program LibreOffice. I would uninstall LibreOffice and gimp. Restart.  Then reinstall LibreOffice. Restart

Comment: I think it's screwed. I'll go a new installation